# Why exactly does a boomerang return back to the thrower?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, aerodynamics, lift

I was always intrigued by the phenomena that govern the returning back  of a boomerang to the thrower.

Even if it is dependent on various factors such as velocity, aerodynamics, wind resistance and so on I was wondering, there must be some concise explanation to it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fundamentally, a boomerang has two arms that spin. One arm spins in the same direction of flight and the other spins away from the direction of flight. For this reason, there's a tilt force on the boomerang.

[image]

Now, since the boomerang is spinning it has angular momentum. Therefore the tilt force generates precession which is pretty much what makes the boomerang come back.

[image]

[Full explanation here.](http://plus.maths.org/issue7/features/boomerangs/index.html)